# Unit testing AngularJS directives

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive

How can I unit test my directive?

What I have is

```
angular.module('MyModule').
    directive('range', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                bindLow: '=',
                bindHigh: '=',
                min: '@',
                max: '@'
            },
        template: '<div><select ng-options="n for n in [min, max] | range" ng-model="bindLow"></select><select ng-options="n for n in [min, max] | range" ng-model="bindHigh"></select></div>'
    };
})
```

In my unit test I want to start with a very simple test

```
describe('Range control', function () {
    var elm, scope;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope) {
        elm = angular.element('<range min="1" max="20" bind-low="low" bind-high="high"></range>');

        var scope = _$rootScope_;
        scope.low = 1;
        scope.high = 20;
        _$compile_(elm)(scope);
        scope.$digest();
    }));

    it('should render two select elements', function() {
        var selects = elm.find('select');

        expect(selects.length).toBe(2);
    });
});
```

This doesn't work though as the directive is registered on the app module and I don't want to include the module as that will make all of my `config` and `run`code run. That would defeat the purpose of testing the directive as a separate unit.

Am I supposed to put all my directives in a separate module and load just that? Or is there any other clever way of solving this?

Comment: note: you defined var scope again inside of beforeEach.  also: _ $rootScope vs _ $rootScope _

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: I see the question has changed since my last answer.

You need to put your directive in an independant module.

For example:

```
angular.module('MyModule.directives');
```

To test only that module you may load that module explicitly in the test like this:

```
beforeEach(module('MyModule.directives'));
```

This will load that module and all its dependancies.

*Remember to state the directive module as a dependancy in your MyModule definition in your app:*

```
angular.module('MyModule', ['MyModule.directives', ...]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should declare all your directives in 'youapp.directives' module and include that module in your directive tests.

In your app.js

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.controllers', 'myApp.directives', 'myApp.services', 'myApp.filters']).config(...)
```

In your directives.js

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', []) .directive(.....)
```

Finally your directivesSpec.js

```
describe('directives specs', function() {
    beforeEach(module('myApp.directives'));

    describe('range', function() {
    ...
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The angular-seed project
https://github.com/angular/angular-seed
seems to have the opinion that directives should go in their own module that is then a dependency of the base app module.

So the directives go in a module called "myApp.directives" :

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', []).
  directive('appVersion', ['version', function(version) {
    return function(scope, elm, attrs) {
      elm.text(version);
    };
  }]);
```

And then the base app module add the directive module as a depenency

```
// Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.filters', 'myApp.services', 'myApp.directives']).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/view1', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial1.html', controller: MyCtrl1});
    $routeProvider.when('/view2', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial2.html', controller: MyCtrl2});
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
  }]);
```

So then their test example just depends on the directive module

```
describe('directives', function() {
  beforeEach(module('myApp.directives'));
etc...
```

I haven't actually tried this with your or my code yet but it looks like you were mostly looking for most common practice guidance.